# Вопрос по .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

надо помощь, есть:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/ catalog.php
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)/ catalog.php?id=$1
```

по адресу (http://www.example.com/catalog/abc/) не передается

```
GET['id']
```

как получить GET['id']?

Comment: я кстати не очень понимаю зачем вы это делаете все таким образом через .htaccess они вообще-то для другого предназначены. отправляйте запросы просто catalog.php  а там уже разбирайте оригинальный запрос. 
по существу вашего вопроса 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

перед 

    RewriteRule ^catalog/ catalog.php

Comment: @eicto, я бы сказал больше, вообще все запросы отправлять через одну точку входа - *index.php*.

@vp111, такой подход, как у вас, это не есть гуд. Я уже не говорю о том, что порой приходиться создавать уйму правил, ошибка которых приводит к ошибке сервера 500. Кроме того, при таком подходе невозможно динамически конфигурировать роутер. Советую пересмотреть свой подход к этому вопросу.

Comment: ну да, мне просто надоело ссылаться на свой сэмпл роутера :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
# RewriteRule ^catalog/ catalog.php
# правило не закрыто, потому ему соответствует ^catalog/.*$
# RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)/ catalog.php?id=$1
# это правило игнорируется
```

---

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# если такого файла нет
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# и папки тоже
RewriteRule ^catalog/?$ catalog.php?&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]+)/?$ catalog.php?&id=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
# закрываем правило справа ($), добавляем модификатор L - дальше не обрабатывать
# %{QUERY_STRING} добавили, чтобы остальные параметры тоже передавались:
#   /catalog/?a=1 --> /catalog.php?a=1
#   /catalog/123/?a=1 --> /catalog.php?id=123&a=1
```

Пробуйте) Утащил с рабочего проекта, должно работать